# Getting GPS coordinates of an ending point based on a specific road, a starting point and length

Tags: google-maps, gps, google-maps-api, api

In an Excel file, through VBA, I would like to have the GPS coordinates of a certain point, starting from the previous known point and the length of a specific highway (or a road). I mean a "delta" calculation based on a specific road and a starting point.
I found out the way to obtain GPS from an address (Google Maps API), but not through a specific road and the distance to the starting (GPS known) point.

Is this possible to do using the Google Maps API or is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have a file with the highways (roads) or do you just have the names?

Comment: Are you looking for  the delta to be a distance along the road or straight-line (Euclidean distance)?

Comment: I just have the names of the highway. I make an example: if I want to know on the highway "autostrada del sole A1" the gps of the point far 120 Km from Milan (starting point of the highway)  I don't know how to do it. Through Google Api I have some entries on this highway (probably just the ones corresponding with the most relevant cities exit, as Rome, Bologna, Naples, Milan, etc.) but not a tracking based on Km from a generic starting point. I hope now is clearer. Thanks a lot. Br. Michele

Comment: Have you any ideas for me?? Thanks in advance